# Issue when I try to use serialized objects in python: when I get them back they lost their type

Tags: python, serialization

I'm working on a computing program where after each step of this program, I serialize data to be able to do a back up in case of crash.

In the last step I have to write reports through xlsxwriter.

So, when I un-serialize data (a list of beam) I can't use methods directly.
Here is the class used to serialize and un-serialize data:

```
import pickle


class Serializer(object):

    @staticmethod
    def serialize(obj):
        return pickle.dumps(obj,protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    @staticmethod
    def unserialize(serializedDatas):
    return pickle.loads (serializedDatas)


    @staticmethod
    def serializeToFile(obj,file):
        return pickle.dump(obj,file,protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    @staticmethod
    def unserializeFile(file):
        return  pickle.load(file)
```

Here is my beam class:

```
from TypeControl import TypeControl
from Point import Point
from Section import Section
import copy
import numpy as np

class Beam(TypeControl):
    def __init__(self,number,Name,Section,pt1,pt2):
        super(self.__class__,self).__init__([],Name)
        self.get().append(TypeControl(pt1,pt1.getName()))
        self.get().append(TypeControl(pt2,pt2.getName()))
        self.get().append(TypeControl(copy.deepcopy(Section),Section.getName()))
        self.get().append(TypeControl(number,"Number"))

    def getPointA (self):
        return self.get()[0].get()
    def getPointB (self):
        return self.get()[1].get()
    def getSection (self):
        return self.get()[2].get()
    def getNumber (self):
        return self.get()[3].get()

    def getLength(self):
        vect=self.getPointA()-self.getPointB()
        return np.sqrt(vect.getx()*vect.getx()+vect.gety()*vect.gety()+vect.getz()*vect.getz())
```

TypeControl is a class used to ensure the type of a data will not change during the execution of the program.

Now let's talk about my problem:

-the problem occur randomly

-when it works b.getName() return a name, when it don't works is executed as "pass" instruction, it don't raise any errors

-I've used the debugger to get more informations:

**b** is supposed to be my Beam object

> (Pdb) b.getName()
>
> *** The specified object '.getName()' is not a function or was not found along sys.path.

**I expected a name** ,getName() is a method of TypeControl Class, it should work.

> (Pdb) Beam.getName(b)
>
> 'ExtColumnHP2_M2'

You might think that I try to use the wrong object due to a confusion. And it may work due to inheritance or something else.

Look at the following:

> (Pdb) b

**it returns nothing in the shell**, I expected something like :

> class 'Beam.Beam'

The question is what is the type of b?

> (Pdb) type(b)
>
> class 'Beam.Beam'

I would like it to return the good type:

> (Pdb) b.**dict**
>
> *** The specified object '.**dict**' is not a function or was not found along sys.path.

In c++, to solve my problem I would have tried: b=(Beam)b

Does someone know why I lost methods linked to this object?

Someone can give me a solution to use b as a common object?

Why before the serialization everything was working well?

The obvious solution is to do something like that: b=Beam(b),but that does not seem very smart.